# Throwing and Catching an Exception

Tags: java

I have a java assignment and I'm somewhat stuck on the following point:

1. Create a WindowMalfunction and PowerOut Events to simulate problems that may occur in a GreenhouseControls. The event should set the following boolean variables as appropriate in GreenhouseControls:
   windowok = false;
   poweron = false;
   After setting the variables, WindowMalfunction or PowerOut should throw an exception specifying the faulty condition. Create a ControllerException class that extends Exception for this purpose.
2. If an exception is thrown from WindowMalfunction or PowerOut, the Controller catches the exception, then initiates an emergency shutdown with an appropriate message. Add a method to Controller called shutdown, and override this method in GreenhouseControls to accomplish the shutdown.
3. Add an instance variable in GreenhouseControls called errorcode. It indicates the nature of the problem with an error code in an int variable errorcode (1 for WindowMalfunction and 2 for PowerOut), logs the time and the reason for the shutdown in a text file in the current directory called error.log and prints it to the console. It then serializes and saves the entire GreenhouseControls object in a file dump.out in the current directory before exiting.

Here is what I've done so far (it's not much) and I'm not entirely sure how to throw and capture exceptions.

```
    private boolean windowork;

    public class WinidowMalfunction extends Event {
        public WinidowMalfunction(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            windowork = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean poweron;

    public class PowerOut extends Event {
        public PowerOut(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            poweron = false;
        }
    }

    public class ControllerException extends Exception {
        public ControllerEception(String except) {
            super(except);
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return super.getMessage();
        }

        public void shutdown() {

        }
    }
```

for a bit of context if needed here is the full project code:
GreenhouseControls.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

import tme3.*;

public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller {
    private boolean light = false;
    private boolean water = false;
    private String thermostat = "Day";
    private String eventsFile = "example1.txt";


    public class LightOn extends Event {
        public LightOn(long delayTime) { super(delayTime); }
        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here to
            // physically turn on the light.
            light = true;
        }
        public String toString() { return "Light is on"; }
    }
    public class LightOff extends Event {
        public LightOff(long delayTime) { super(delayTime); }
        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here to
            // physically turn off the light.
            light = false;
        }
        public String toString() { return "Light is off"; }
    }
    public class WaterOn extends Event {
        public WaterOn(long delayTime) { super(delayTime); }
        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            water = true;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Greenhouse water is on";
        }
    }
    public class WaterOff extends Event {
        public WaterOff(long delayTime) { super(delayTime); }
        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            water = false;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Greenhouse water is off";
        }
    }
    public class ThermostatNight extends Event {
        public ThermostatNight(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }
        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            thermostat = "Night";
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Thermostat on night setting";
        }
    }
    public class ThermostatDay extends Event {
        public ThermostatDay(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }
        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            thermostat = "Day";
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Thermostat on day setting";
        }
    }

    // An example of an action() that inserts a
    // new one of itself into the event list:
    public class Bell extends Event {
        public Bell(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            addEvent(new Bell(delayTime));
        }

        public String toString() { return "Bing!"; }
    }

    private boolean fans;

    public class FansOn extends Event {
        public FansOn(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            fans = true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Fans are on";
        }
    }

    public class FansOff extends Event {
        public FansOff(long delayTime) {
            super (delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            fans = false;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Fans are off";
        }
    }

    private boolean windowork;

    public class WinidowMalfunction extends Event {
        public WinidowMalfunction(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            windowork = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean poweron;

    public class PowerOut extends Event {
        public PowerOut(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            poweron = false;
        }
    }

    public class ControllerException extends Exception {
        public ControllerEception(String except) {
            super(except);
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return super.getMessage();
        }

        public void shutdown() {

        }
    }

    public class Restart extends Event {
        public Restart(long delayTime, String filename) {
            super(delayTime);
            eventsFile = filename;
        }

        public void action() {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(eventsFile);
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
            }

            addEvent(new ThermostatNight(0));
            addEvent(new LightOn(2000));
            addEvent(new WaterOff(8000));
            addEvent(new ThermostatDay(10000));
            addEvent(new Bell(2000));
            addEvent(new WaterOn(6000));
            addEvent(new LightOff(4000));
            addEvent(new Terminate(12000));
            addEvent(new FansOn(5000));
            addEvent(new FansOff(1000));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Restarting system";
        }
    }

    public class Terminate extends Event {
        public Terminate(long delayTime) { super(delayTime); }
        public void action() { System.exit(0); }
        public String toString() { return "Terminating";  }
    }


    public static void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("Correct format: ");
        System.out.println("  java GreenhouseControls -f <filename>, or");
        System.out.println("  java GreenhouseControls -d dump.out");
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String option = args[0];
            String filename = args[1];

            if ( !(option.equals("-f")) && !(option.equals("-d")) ) {
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
                printUsage();
            }

            GreenhouseControls gc = new GreenhouseControls();

            if (option.equals("-f"))  {
                gc.addEvent(gc.new Restart(0,filename));
            }

            gc.run();
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of parameters");
            printUsage();
        }
    }

} ///:~
```

Controller.java

```
package tme3;
import java.util.*;


public class Controller {
  // A class from java.util to hold Event objects:
  private List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
  public void addEvent(Event c) { eventList.add(c); }

  public void run() {
    while(eventList.size() > 0)
      // Make a copy so you're not modifying the list
      // while you're selecting the elements in it:
      for(Event e : new ArrayList<Event>(eventList))
        if(e.ready()) {
          System.out.println(e);
          e.action();
          eventList.remove(e);
        }
  }
} ///:~
```

Event.java

```
package tme3;

import java.io.*;

public abstract class Event {
  private long eventTime;
  protected final long delayTime;
  public Event(long delayTime) {
    this.delayTime = delayTime;
    start();
  }
  public void start() { // Allows restarting
    eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayTime;
  }
  public boolean ready() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() >= eventTime;
  }
  public abstract void action();
} ///:~
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Comment added to understand it.

GreenhouseControls.java

```
package tme3;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller {
    private boolean light = false;
    private boolean water = false;
    private String thermostat = "Day";
    private String eventsFile = "example1.txt";

    // 3. Add an instance variable in GreenhouseControls called error code.
    private int errorCode;

    public class LightOn extends Event {
        public LightOn(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here to
            // physically turn on the light.
            light = true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Light is on";
        }
    }

    public class LightOff extends Event {
        public LightOff(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here to
            // physically turn off the light.
            light = false;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Light is off";
        }
    }

    public class WaterOn extends Event {
        public WaterOn(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            water = true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Greenhouse water is on";
        }
    }

    public class WaterOff extends Event {
        public WaterOff(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            water = false;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Greenhouse water is off";
        }
    }

    public class ThermostatNight extends Event {
        public ThermostatNight(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            thermostat = "Night";
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Thermostat on night setting";
        }
    }

    public class ThermostatDay extends Event {
        public ThermostatDay(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            // Put hardware control code here.
            thermostat = "Day";
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Thermostat on day setting";
        }
    }

    // An example of an action() that inserts a
    // new one of itself into the event list:
    public class Bell extends Event {
        public Bell(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            addEvent(new Bell(delayTime));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Bing!";
        }
    }

    private boolean fans;

    public class FansOn extends Event {
        public FansOn(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            fans = true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Fans are on";
        }
    }

    public class FansOff extends Event {
        public FansOff(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            fans = false;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Fans are off";
        }
    }

    private boolean windowork;

    public class WinidowMalfunction extends Event {

        public WinidowMalfunction(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        // 1. After setting the variables, WindowMalfunction or PowerOut should throw an
        // exception specifying the faulty condition
        public void action() throws ControllerException {
            windowork = false;
            // 3. error code in an int variable error code -> 1 for WindowMalfunction
            someThingWentWrongHere(1, "Error at WinidowMalfunction");
        }

    }

    private boolean poweron;

    public class PowerOut extends Event {

        public PowerOut(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);

        }

        // 1. After setting the variables, WindowMalfunction or PowerOut should throw an
        // exception specifying the faulty condition
        public void action() throws ControllerException {
            poweron = false;
            // 3. error code in an int variable error code -> 2 for powerOut
            someThingWentWrongHere(2, "Error at powerOut event");
        }

    }

    void someThingWentWrongHere(int errorCode, String errorMessage) throws ControllerException {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        throw new ControllerException(errorMessage);
    }

    public class ControllerException extends Exception {
        public ControllerException(String except) {
            super(except);
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return super.getMessage();
        }

        public void shutdown() {

        }
    }

    public class Restart extends Event {
        public Restart(long delayTime, String filename) {
            super(delayTime);
            eventsFile = filename;
        }

        public void action() {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(eventsFile);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
            }

            addEvent(new ThermostatNight(0));
            addEvent(new LightOn(2000));
            addEvent(new WaterOff(8000));
            addEvent(new ThermostatDay(10000));
            addEvent(new Bell(2000));
            addEvent(new WaterOn(6000));
            addEvent(new LightOff(4000));
            addEvent(new Terminate(12000));
            addEvent(new FansOn(5000));
            addEvent(new FansOff(1000));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Restarting system";
        }
    }

    public class Terminate extends Event {
        public Terminate(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Terminating";
        }
    }

    public static void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("Correct format: ");
        System.out.println("  java GreenhouseControls -f <filename>, or");
        System.out.println("  java GreenhouseControls -d dump.out");
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GreenhouseControls gc = new GreenhouseControls();

        try {
            /*
             * String option = args[0]; String filename = args[1];
             * 
             * if (!(option.equals("-f")) && !(option.equals("-d"))) {
             * System.out.println("Invalid option"); printUsage(); }
             * 
             * if (option.equals("-f")) { gc.addEvent(gc.new Restart(0, filename)); }
             */

            // UnCommenting above code will never test below code because above code with
            // throw first exception and it will never execute below code

            // To test PowerOut fail with exception
            // gc.addEvent(gc.new PowerOut(100));

            // To test WinidowMalfunction fail with exception
            gc.addEvent(gc.new WinidowMalfunction(100));

            gc.run();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of parameters");
            printUsage();
        }
        // 2. the Controller catches the exception
        catch (ControllerException e) {
            // 2. then initiates an emergency shutdown with an appropriate message
            gc.shutdown(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    // override this method in GreenhouseControls to accomplish the shutdown.
    @Override
    protected void shutdown(String message) {
        // super.shutdown();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateobj = new Date();

        // logs the time and the reason for the shutdown in a text file ,, Here you will
        // create file and log it
        System.out.println("Shutdown due to Error: " + message + " | Error Code:" + errorCode + " | DateTime:" + df.format(dateobj));
    }

    /*
     * enum ErrorCode { WindowMalfunction, PowerOut }
     */
}
```

Controller.java

```
package tme3;

import java.util.*;

import tme3.GreenhouseControls.ControllerException;

public class Controller {
    // A class from java.util to hold Event objects:
    private List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();

    public void addEvent(Event c) {
        eventList.add(c);
    }

    public void run()  throws ControllerException{
        while (eventList.size() > 0)
            // Make a copy so you're not modifying the list
            // while you're selecting the elements in it:
            for (Event e : new ArrayList<Event>(eventList))
                if (e.ready()) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.action();
                    eventList.remove(e);
                }
    }

    //2. Add a method to Controller called shutdown,
    protected void shutdown(String message) {
        System.out.println("ShutDown from controller");
    }
}
```

Event.java

```
package tme3;

import tme3.GreenhouseControls.ControllerException;

public abstract class Event {
    private long eventTime;
    protected final long delayTime;

    public Event(long delayTime) {
        this.delayTime = delayTime;
        start();
    }

    public void start() { // Allows restarting
        eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayTime;
    }

    public boolean ready() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() >= eventTime;
    }

    public abstract void action()  throws ControllerException;
}
```

Comment: You should learn the exception(Compile-time and runtime) handling.

Comment: I'm not following should I be using try-catch this is what i understand from the question so what does exception(Compile-time and runtime) handling relate to it